# Getting CPU (user and system) and real usage time of child processes in C

Tags: c, linux, time, exec, cpu-usage

So I have a job for my OS class and one of the increased value options it to add, when listing the process ID and name of the commands I have running, the CPU time and the real usage time of the same commands. Thing is, I can only get them after they have finished, using the times() function and the information is supposed to appear **while** they are running. Is there any way to do this?

I am launching commands by forking the parent process and then running `execlp("xterm","xterm","-hold", "-e", command, NULL)` on the child. As you can see, the -hold prevents the window from closing instantly, which, on the one hand, ables me to see the output of a date command, for example, but on the other hand makes the xterm hang until I close it with either kill() or directly on the xterm window.

All help is appreciated. Thank you. :)

Note: The OS is Linux (I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 but the code should work on all distros).

Answer (score 1):

You can read this information from `/proc/pid/stat`, where *`pid`* is the process ID that you're interested in.

See the [proc man pages](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html) for details.

Look also at `ps -o format`, which allows you to select the fields that `ps` should display.  Again, see the [man pages](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ps) for details.

Comment: But do I have to read the entire file every single time I want to show the input? Isn't that a little too cumbersome?